# Why is TS "unable to find module" using basic imports?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to get started on a basic project with Apollo GraphQL using TS instead of regular ES/JS.

I've gotten some very basic code written, but at the current moment, I am continuously getting this error when trying to handle what appears to be...a basic relative import in my code:

`Cannot find module '/Users/czbaker/Projects/express-apollo-ts/dist/gql/resolvers' imported from /Users/czbaker/Projects/express-apollo-ts/dist/main.js`

I completely fail to understand why this is occurring.  Here's what I've got going on:

**src/main.ts**

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import http, { Server } from 'http';
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// GQL
import { resolvers } from './gql/resolvers';
import { typeDefs } from './gql/typeDefs';


// Load config
const envpath: string = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env');
dotenv.config({
    path: envpath,
    debug: true
});

// Create Apollo Server
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    resolvers, 
    typeDefs,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })]
});
await server.start();

// Use Middleware
app.use(expressMiddleware(server));

// Launch Server
await new Promise<void>((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.SERVER_PORT }, resolve));
console.log(`Server available at http://localhost:${process.env.SERVER_PORT}/`);
```

**src/gql/resolvers.ts**

```
export const resolvers: any = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => "World!"
    }
}
```

**src/gql/typeDefs.ts**

```
export const typeDefs = `#graphql
    type Query {
        hello: String;
    }
`
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "rootDirs": ["src"],
      "outDir": "dist",
      "lib": ["es2020"],
      "target": "es2020",
      "module": "ES6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "types": ["node"],
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "express-apollo-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Apollo GraphQL server via Express/TypeScript/Mongoose w/ Subscription support",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "repository": "https://github.com/czbak3r/express-apollo-ts",
  "author": "Charles Baker",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/main.js\"",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "nodemon ./dist/main.js"
  }
}
```

The end result thus far is that TSC has no issue compiling the code, but when it's executed, I get the previously mentioned error.

I clearly have `resolvers.ts` defined and get no errors importing at the time of compilation or in VSCode, so what's causing this issue?

I've tried this both using tsc (in watch mode) **and** using `ts-node`, but the end result is the same.  From the research and searching I was able to do, this might be because of ESM?  I'm coming back from a programming hiatus and have never heard of ESM before, so...that would be entirely new to me.

**Edit:**
Upon looking at output files, I have the following structure in `/dist`:

```
main.js
  - /gql
    - resolvers.js
    - typeDefs.js
```

I've read in some places that import statements have to have file extensions depending on various settings...does this cause an issue here?

It looks like all of the files are being output properly when compiled and the `import` statements of the compiled code are intact, so...I still fail to understand why it's apparently not seeing the stuff in `./gql/` at runtime.

Comment: Do you need the compiler option: "rootDirs": ["src"]? Maybe you mean "rootDir": "src"?

Comment: Tried switching to `"rootDir": "src"` and it had no effect, still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when you're using imports for files in your project, you're required to use the `.js` extension as such:

```
import { resolvers } from './gql/resolvers.js';
import { typeDefs } from './gql/typeDefs.js';
```

This is not a bug but a feature of TypeScript, according to further research.

Not sure why this is the default behavior, but as long as it functions the way that it should and VSCode isn't angry, then I'll roll with it.

Hope this also helps someone!   :)

Comment: Definitely the easiest way to solve your present problem, but it does seem there is something deeper going on. My TS projects, either in Node or the browser, do not use ".js" extensions and neither do the documented examples. Something seems to be going on with Node's module resolution in your setup.